# Search the full group $G$ based on the partial list of its matrix representations

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, algebra, group-theory

Suppose I have a list of matrices that may represent the partial list of the full group $G$. And here are the given set of 7 matrix elements.

$$e =\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} $$
$$
i =\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 \\
  1 & -1
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
$$
j =\begin{pmatrix}
 -1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1
\end{pmatrix} $$
$$
k =\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & -1 \\
  1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} $$
$$
\overline{e} = \begin{pmatrix}
  -1 & 0 \\
  0 & -1
\end{pmatrix} $$
$$
\overline{i} =\begin{pmatrix}
  -1 & -1 \\
  -1 & 1
\end{pmatrix} $$
$$
\overline{j} =\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & -1 \\
  -1 & -1
\end{pmatrix} $$

How do I use Mathematica function to effectively

> (1) find the full group $G$ based on the above lists?
>
> (2) find the missing group elements in the $G$ not given in the above list? Thus, also determine the total number of group elements in the $G$?
>
> (3) How to find **a Multiplication Table** in terms of the entry of these matrix representations? (for example, using FiniteGroupData["Quaternion", "MultiplicationTable"] )

(The above question is just a trial problem. In this case, I already know the answer: The missing entry is $\overline{k} =\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 \\
  -1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$, and the full group is the [order 8 qauternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group#Matrix_representations).)

But how do we find an effective algorithm in Mathematica to help to solve similar problems?

Thanks!

(Edit: Finding the Multiplication Table is enough, no need for character table...)

Comment: (1) and (2) can be done via a `FixedPoint` and `Union` scheme like `FixedPoint[Union[Table[Map[el*#&, #], {el, #}]], els]` or something. I use a similar tactic [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-ChemTools/blob/315dbd7a10ffd169d7a435825f7a429ff99b1ed3/Packages/Utilities/Symmetry.m#L1786) to (inefficiently) enumerate all of the symmetry planes in a molecule. I only know (3) in the context of symmetry operations so can't help you there. [This](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717108800776) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/86369/547370) might help though.

Comment: @ b3m2a1 +1, feel free to write an answer to clarify how to input these 7 matrices to generate the full group. I guess that as long as one can obtain the full set of group elements $\{g_a\}$, then one can compute the character table from the multiplications $g_a g_b$, then it is enough for me to compare with some mathematics group theory data book.

Comment: (Edit: Finding the Multiplication Table is enough, no need for character table...)

Comment: @  b3m2a1, I am not sure that I can read or digest this --" FixedPoint[Union[Table[Map[el*#&, #], {el, #}]], els]"... -- can you write an answer for it: ?